# Python subprocess.check_call() not recognising pushd and popd

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, subprocess, ubuntu-15.04

I'm on Ubuntu 15.04 (not by choice obviously) and Python 3.4.3 and I'm trying to execute something like the following.

```
subprocess.check_call("pushd /tmp", shell=True)
```

I need the `shell=True` because the actual code I'm trying to execute contains wildcards that need to be interpreted. However, this gives me the following error.

```
/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py in check_call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    559         if cmd is None:
    560             cmd = popenargs[0]
--> 561         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    562     return 0
    563 

CalledProcessError: Command 'pushd /tmp' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

I've tried doing the same thing on my Mac (El Capitan and Python 3.5.1) and it works perfectly. I've also tried executing `subprocess.check_call("ls", shell=True)` on the Ubuntu 15.04 with Python 3.4.3 (for sanity check), and it works fine. As a final sanity check, I've tried the command `pushd /tmp && popd` in Bash on the Ubuntu 15.04 and that works fine too. So somehow, on (my) Ubuntu 15.04 with Python 3.4.3, `subprocess.check_call()` does not recognise `pushd` and `popd`! Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two problems with your code. The first one is that the shell used by default is `/bin/sh` which doesn't support `pushd` and `popd`. 
In your question you failed to provide the whole error output, and at the top of it you should see the line:

```
/bin/sh: 1: popd: not found
```

The next time rememeber to post the *whole* error message, and not just the portion that *you* (incorrectly) think is relevant.

You can fix this by telling the `subprocess` module which shell to use via the `executable` argument:

```
>>> subprocess.check_call('pushd ~', shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
~ ~
0
```

The second problem is that even with this you will get an error if you use multiple `check_call` calls:

```
>>> subprocess.check_call('pushd ~', shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
~ ~
0
>>> subprocess.check_call('popd', shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
/bin/bash: riga 0: popd: stack delle directory vuoto
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 581, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'popd' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

This is because every call to `check_call` starts a **new** subshells, and thus it doesn't matter whether you previously called `pushd` because the directory stack will always be empty.

Note that if you try to combine `pushd` and `popd` in a single call they *do* work:

```
>>> subprocess.check_call('pushd ~ && popd', shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
~ ~
~
0
```

Now fact is, if you were thinking of using `pushd` and `popd` in that way from python... they are *useless*. That's because you can specify the current working directory via the `cwd` argument, and so you can keep track of the stack of working directories from python without having to rely on `pushd` and `popd`:

```
current_working_dirs = []

def pushd(dir):
    current_working_dirs.append(os.path.realpath(os.path.expanduser(dir)))

def popd():
    current_working_dirs.pop()


def run_command(cmdline, **kwargs):
    return subprocess.check_call(cmdline, cwd=current_working_dirs[-1], **kwargs)
```

Replace `check_call('pushd xxx')` with `pushd('xxx')` and `check_call('popd')` with `popd` and use `run_command(...)` instead of `check_call(...)`.

---

As you suggest a more elegant solution would be to use a context manager:

```
class Pwd:
    dir_stack = []

    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = os.path.realpath(os.path.expanduser(self.dirname))

    def __enter__(self):
        Pwd.dir_stack.append(self.dirname)
        return self

    def __exit__(self,  type, value, traceback):
        Pwd.dir_stack.pop()

    def run(self, cmdline, **kwargs):
        return subprocess.check_call(cmdline, cwd=Pwd.dir_stack[-1], **kwargs)
```

used as:

```
with Pwd('~') as shell:
    shell.run(command)
    with Pwd('/other/directory') as shell:
        shell.run(command2)   # runs in '/other/directory'
    shell.run(command3)       # runs in '~'
```

Comment: I've edited my question now. Sorry I made a mistake early. I know that `check_call()` spawn a new shell. The problem is not with calling `popd` after calling `pushd`; it's really is with `pushd` itself.

Comment: @Ray Based on your updates, the key part of Bakuriu's answer is that the shell is not bash so there is no pushd available. On Ubuntu try to start sh and do a pushd.

Comment: @Ray I've reorganized my answer to be clearer. Also: IMHO pushd and popd are useless if you are writing in python, just use a list of strings as stack and pass the right `cwd=` parameter to subprocess calls.

Comment: Thank you @Bakuriu. I failed to provide the whole error output because I was running it in Jupyter Notebook, which didn't print as much error message as the vanilla Python shell. Had I used the vanilla Python shell I might have noticed it.

Comment: @Bakuriu also I agree with you that `pushd` and `popd` should be replaced with something more Pythonic, I'm thinking a context class named `pushd` with `__enter__` and `__exit__` implemented so I can use the with statement. But I was writing some quick and dirty admin stuff that required a significant amount of Python and this problem caught my curiosity.